# Result of Main.isLeapYear is ignored - why?

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        isLeapYear(1600);
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
    {
        if (year < 1 || year > 9999) return false;

        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? no output is shown when I run the code.

Comment: What output do you expect this program to produce?

Comment: You are printing anything! How can you expect output?

Comment: it is not ignored, you just haven't written any code that would do anything with the result

Comment: Well... _You_ are ignoring the return value of that method, not intellij. You just call the method without printing the result, that's why you have no output.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(isLeapYear(1600));`

Comment: Why do you think years outside of the range 1 - 9999 are not leap years?

Comment: @Michael its because of people like OP, Y2K happened lol

Comment: @Michael leap years (according to the rules we know them now) have only existed since 1582. Not saying anything about 9999, but chances of the rules of now being applied before the year 1 are zip

Comment: @Stultuske That's spurious reasoning. How does that imply that a lower bound of 1 is appropriate?

Comment: @Stultuske AFAIK leap year (every 4 years then) where introduced around 45 BC

Comment: @Michael it was a challenge assignment from udemy course so i had to do things as the question mentioned. Just a student :)

Comment: you can just use 'java.time.Year.of(year).isLeap()' without create your own method

Comment: @Berger thanks it worked

Comment: @GyroGearless yes, but at that time, a year had around 355 days. And, though a lot of the "rules" were the same: In 1582, Pope Gregory XIII further refined the calendar with the rule that leap day would occur in any year divisible by 4 as described above.
So, want to keep that check? either make it a lot more complicated, or 'change histories calendars'

Comment: When I was a beginner, I also all the time forgot to print my results and wondered why my program didn’t print anything. I suspect it’s a very common beginner’s bug. It has also been asked on Stack Overflow before (sorry, didn’t readily find other instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No output is displayed as you are not displaying anything, to display the output try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        System.out.println(isLeapYear(1600));
}
```